# A question related to Kirillov model

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations, local-fields

I am reading [Jackson - The theory of admissible representations of $\operatorname{GL}(2, F)$](https://doi.org/10.7939/R3MK65G79) and am not able to understand the following map related to Kirillov model. This result appears on p. 54:

[image: Proposition 27]

I am not able to understand how the map is defined i.e. what does it mean by $\sigma(g)\varphi := (\pi_\psi(g)\varphi(b^{-1}\cdot))(b~\cdot)$.

Any help regarding this would be really appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be quoting from a paper.  What paper?

Comment: I have edited the question. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: In the notation of pp. 51 ff., $\varphi(b^{-1}\cdot)$ is the function $a \mapsto \varphi(b^{-1}a)$ on $F^\times$.  I'm pretty sure that $\varphi$ is supposed to come from $V_{\psi'}$, not $V_\psi$.  Then $\varphi(b^{-1}\cdot)$ belongs to $V_\psi$, and so is of the form $\varphi_v$ (really $\varphi_{\psi, v}$) for some $v \in V$.  Then $\pi_\psi(g)\varphi(b^{-1}\cdot)$ is the function $\varphi_{\pi(g)v}$, and $(\pi_\psi(g)\varphi(b^{-1}\cdot))(b\cdot)$ is the function $a \mapsto \varphi_{\pi(g)v}(b a)$ on $F^\times$. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @LSpice  That means the definition of $\sigma$ is not correct since the author considered $\varphi \in V_\psi$. Am I right?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1211499), there's *some* notational mistake; I'm not 100% sure it's $V_{\psi'}$ versus $V_\psi$, or that, if so, that's the only mistake, but it's a likely candidate.  [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1211503), $\sigma(g)\varphi \mathrel{:=} (\pi_\psi(g)\varphi(b^{-1}\cdot))(b\cdot)$ *is* the definition of $\sigma$, except, if I've got it right, that it should be applied to $\varphi$ in $V_{\psi'}$ instead of in $V_\psi$, by telling you the action via $g \in G$ of $\varphi$ on a typical element of $V_{\psi'}$.

Comment: @LSpice Considering it was a typo, so far it has been shown that $(\sigma, V_{\psi'}) \cong (\pi_{\psi},  V_{\psi})$ and  $(\sigma, V_{\psi'}) = (\pi_{\psi'},  V_{\psi'})$. The only thing needs to be shown is that $V_\psi = V_{\psi'}$. Am I correct?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1211505), no, the claim is that $(\pi_\psi, V_\psi)$ and $(\pi_{\psi'}, V_{\psi'})$ are equivalent, not equal.  This follows from $(\pi_{\psi'}, V_{\psi'}) = (\sigma, V_{\psi'}) \cong (\pi_\psi, V_\psi)$.

Comment: @LSpice In the statement of the theorem, the author claims that the two vector spaces are actually equal. I am not sure if it will be required to prove the other theorems later in that article, but the claim seems quite interesting.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1211509), sorry, I didn't read carefully.  I agree that the question of equality remains.  If correct, then that would mean that my [claim](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1211504) about a typo might be wrong.  I think that understanding this claim requires understanding the relation between $\pi_\psi$ and $\xi_\psi$, which I don't have time to do at the moment.